# Kinetic.js Load Issues

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to load a saved stage from a database and when I load it, it looks fine, but after loading it I cannot draw on the stage. I'm aware that I might not be able to use the loaded objects like I could before saving, but how can I draw onto the stage after loading?

I am using `Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container');`
but afterwards I can no longer add to the stage with `layer.draw();`.

Does anyone have any suggestions? And what is a good way to re-bind event handlers. Are there any good tutorials? Thank you!

EDIT:

Here is my code for creating and editing the canvas.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width:screen.width*.98,
        height: screen.height*.70,
        id:'stage',
        name: 'stage'
      });

      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      layer.on('mousedown',function(e){ 
      var node = e.targetNode;
      //select(node);
      });

//load
var json= load();
stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container');
```

Answer (score 3):

**Q1: Re-instantiating a Kinetic.Stage.**

Your `Kinetic.Node.create` command is the correct command to re-instantiate a stage.  Further diagnosis was not possible since you provided no code.

```
var stage = Kinetic.Node.create(yourJSON, 'container');
stage.draw();
```

**Q2: Re-binding event handlers.**

One good way of rewiring event handlers is to provide a .js file along with your .json file.

For example:

When creating your nodes/containers, add properties to indicate which event handler(s) need to be rewired:

```
var circle1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x:100,
    y:100,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'red',

    // this circle should be rewired with myClickHandler1
    clickEvent:"myClickHandler1"

});
```

Put all your event handlers in a .js file that's provided along with your .json file:

```
var eventHandlers={
    myClickHandler1:function(e){alert("Fired clickHandler1");},
}
```

And then you can rewire the event handlers from the .js file like this:

```
function rewireHandlers(node){

    var handler;

    // rewire click handler
    handler=node.getAttr("clickEvent");
    if(handler && eventHandlers[handler]){
        node.on("click",eventHandlers[handler])
    }

    // rewire other event handlers the same way
}

// rewire all nodes and containers

stage.getChildren().each(function(node){
   node.rewireHandlers(node);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll try that, and I've posted my canvas creation and load code above if you wanted to look at that, I'm not sure if that tells you what my problem might be. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First  in your json string you need to replace all "className" : "Kinetic.Group" to "className" : "Group" then try